# I use flutter_modular and I need to dynamically create the custom transitions. How I can do this?

Tags: flutter, dart, modular, flutter-module

I use flutter_modular and I need to dynamically create the custom transitions. How I can do this?
I have one more question. How can I do Modular.to.pushReplacementNamed without route name?

Comment: `dynamically create the custom transactions` what do you mean by custom transactions?

Comment: I have ChildRoute. Every time when I navigate to this route I need to use another transition.

Comment: Do you have any solution?